# iPad won't run app built in Xcode & it finishes right after building

Tags: xcode, ipad, swift

When I run my application on my iPad, the application opens then closes instantaneously after "build succeeded". I can run my app on iPhones without problems. My iPad iOS version is 8.1 and my Xcode is 6.2.

I get no error message just "CoreFoundation = 1141.140000" as output. I have searched the web up and down, but can't seem to get an answer. Does anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried breakpointing anywhere?  Do the initial methods get called, like `application:didFinishLaunching` in AppDelegate or `viewDidLoad` on the initial viewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the Ipad because it was jailbraked. After reinstalling it all worked fine.